# Are there any studies for or against frequent password changes?

Tags: security, passwords

I'm looking for studies on the security effect of frequent password changes, looking at the security benefits / problems from having a mandatory password change every one or two months or similar.

Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://cryptosmith.com/password-sanity/exp-harmful/) is a research article on password policy. It mentions the frequency at which people should change their passwords and some other really interesting stuff. Below is an extract.

> Some experts say that periodic
>   password changes will reduce the
>   damage if an attacker intercepts a
>   password: once the password is
>   changed, the attacker is locked out.
>   This assumes that the recovered
>   password will not give the attacker
>   any hints about the victim's current
>   password. In fact, periodic password
>   changes tend to encourage people to
>   design sequences of passwords, like
>   secret01a, secret01b, secret01c, and
>   so on.
>
> This allows users to easily choose and
>   remember a new password when the old
>   one expires. Such sequences are
>   usually pretty obvious to an attacker,
>   so any one of the victim's old
>   passwords will probably provide the
>   attacker with a reasonably small
>   number of passwords to guess at.

Answer (score 5):

The TechReport [Do Strong Web Passwords Accomplish Anything?](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70445/tr-2007-64.pdf) states “changing
the password frequently helps only if the attacker is extremely slow to exploit the harvested credentials.”

Comment: Good point. That suggests that a high quality of passwords has a better effect than a high frequency of updates.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, forcing people to change their password too often, reduces security because the only way people can remember so many passwords, is to start using stupid passwords like Computer123 or January1 followed by February1 etc...

A better idea is to reduce the frequency and then train people how to create strong passwords.

Answer (score 4):

While not *exactly* the study you're looking for, it is closely related and might push you in the right direction. I have seen a few studies on the specific topic you're looking for, but can't find the references just yet.

[Microsoft Security Guru advice: "Write down your password"](http://news.cnet.com/Microsoft-security-guru-Jot-down-your-passwords/2100-7355_3-5716590.html)

There are a number of bad things that can happen with passwords, and want to mitigate as many as possible without creating new problems. The "change your password" policy is there to mitigate the damage over time that could be caused if your password gets out, by limiting the window of opportunity for an attacker. While not the end-all of security measures, it can sometimes make a huge difference. As a security consultant, I have personally made (this year alone) many tens of thousands of dollars cleaning up messes that could have been avoided entirely if the company had changed important passwords at least yearly.

The danger of changing your password frequently is that you'll pick poor passwords. This makes the situation even worse, because it now allows attacks that would have otherwise not been possible.

The new wisdom, as mentioned in the linked article, is pick (or be assigned) a random password, possibly changed on a regular basis, and write it down somewhere that you keep safe. Obviously you don't leave it with your computer any more than you would leave you keys with your car. The justification is that people are already trained to know how to secure "things" but are naturally poor at securing information. So if you turn the password into a thing you can hold, then you can just secure it the same way you secure your keys. In practice, this works very well, however it tends to make IT departments nervous.

Comment: Interesting link! Thanks! 

Changing passwords yearly, that's one thing, but with "frequent" I was thinking about monthly and bi-monthly mandatory changes.

Answer (score 4):

Update, August 2016:

This article: "Frequent password changes are the enemy of security, FTC technologist says" http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/08/frequent-password-changes-are-the-enemy-of-security-ftc-technologist-says/?imm_mid=0e6947&cmp=em-webops-na-na-newsltr_security_20160809
has been showing up everywhere this week, including Bruce Scheier's blog, O'Reilly's Security Newsletter, ArsTechnica, Slate, and NewsCombinator, and may be just exactly what you'd asked for earlier this year.

It references:
https://www.cs.unc.edu/~reiter/papers/2010/CCS.pdf

TL;DR summary: Stop expiring/changing passwords.  It's a really bad security practice.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any studies that exist, but to get you thinking about both sides of the issue, here's a paper against forcing password changes:

[Managing network security — Part 10: Change your password](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6VJG-3WNN2SR-3&_user=88470&_rdoc=1&_fmt=&_orig=search&_sort=d&view=c&_acct=C000006998&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=88470&md5=2881320c4a258bcb50c15b9c5fdb7426)

And an instructional site for an educational institute that makes at least a somewhat compelling case (Written by a Ph.D.) for forcing users to change their passwords frequently.  These are the main arguments the site gives FOR forcing password changes, after the link to the page:

["Why Do I Have to Change My !@$%#* Password?"](http://cc.uoregon.edu/cnews/spring2006/passwords.htm)

- If you're required to change your
  password at least every six months,
  someone who's hacked your password
  and has been accessing your account
  without your knowledge will
  immediately be shut out once your
  password is changed. Some may think
  this is an uncommon scenario, but
  people commonly sell an old computer
  and forget to erase passwords they
  may have saved for dialing in or for
  accessing their email.
- If you change your password at least
  every six months, hackers who may be
  trying to crack your password using
  brute force (as described above)
  basically need to start over because
  your password may now have been
  changed to some pattern they've
  already tried and rejected.
- Forcing a password change also
  discourages users from using the same
  password on multiple accounts. (Using
  the same password on multiple
  accounts is bad because then your
  password is only as secure as the
  least secure of the systems sharing
  that common password, and if your
  account does get compromised, the bad
  guy suddenly has access not just to
  one account, but to multiple
  accounts, magnifying the scope of the
  problem).

As far as "research" goes, these might not cut it, but seem to be at least a good introduction to both sides of the argument.

Comment: Arguments are not data points.  Take 90 day passwords...I want empirical data that says changing passwords every 90 days is more secure than every 86 days, or every 113 days, or once every six months, I don't want arguments.  Of course the world doesn't often bow to my whims...

Answer (score 3):

It's not a study, but Gene Spafford posted a short article that discusses the reasons why a policy of frequent password changes doesn't make much sense:

- http://www.cerias.purdue.edu/site/blog/post/password-change-myths/

Answer (score 2):

Passwords should be changed when you believe that your password may have been or may soon be compromised.  Otherwise, it is usually a useless waste of time, and actually a security hazard. See this link:

http://old.news.yahoo.com/s/ytech_wguy/20100413/tc_ytech_wguy/ytech_wguy_tc1590

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent paper published in an ACM publication (from 2010) that discusses the cost-benefit analysis of security and user expectations.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cormac/papers/2009/SoLongAndNoThanks.pdf

It does make the claim that changing passwords is certainly good advice, but it may not be worth the cost to the users since there is so little evidence to support the idea that we are safer with more frequent password changes.  It really is such a good article.